# Admin model categories, Keystone 4

Tags: keystonejs

Anybody know how to make keystone 4 admin ui categories. By default you get "Users" and "Other" on the admin dashboard. I would love to group my models a bit.

Answer (score 0):

This is done by setting the `nav` property in your root `keystone.js` file. See [this example](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone-demo/blob/master/keystone.js#L47) from the demo site, which shows both single items and arrays being used.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to set custom icons?

Comment: Hmmm good question! I'm fairly sure that functionality doesn't exist. What does exist is a set of pre-built icons. See here: https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/blob/master/admin/client/App/screens/Home/utils/getRelatedIconClass.js

If you use anything in the `Sections` array you should get the corresponding icon.

Comment: That said, the `this.props.item` here makes me think maybe you can do it somehow. Not sure how though, sorry. 
https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/blob/master/admin/client/App/screens/Home/components/Section.js#L6

Comment: The this.props.item is only used for setting the default icon for models that are not in a specific section. You can find out in this file: https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/blob/master/admin/client/App/screens/Home/index.js

It's setting the database icon as default, although the icon doesn't render due to a bug that the octicon class isn't sey correctly by keystone.